# Optimizing queries over date ranges in MongoDb (with other fields)

Tags: mongodb

I'm building a scheduling/booking system where a bunch of providers serve customers at a bunch of locations on certain times.

My appointment object looks like this:

```
{
    "providerName" : {"type": "string"},
    "location" : {"type": "string"},
    "startTime" : {"type": "TBA"},
    "endTime" : {"type": "TBA"},
}
```

The appointments are stored in MongoDb and I'll need to run a lot of searches with all 4 fields set (there will probably be 10-20 searches for each insertion, so I'm optimizing for reads here).

I'm thinking to store the start and end times in milliseconds, and set up a compound index on these two, then set up 2 separate indices on the provider name and location.

But I'm wondering whether I can improve the performance (end reduce the load on the server) using some extra optimizations:

- What's more efficient for range queries - storing the start/end time as milliseconds/Long or as java.util.Date or maybe a String?
- If I'm interested in searches by date only, perhaps I should represent time as string (e.g. 2015/10/11) and search by lexicographic range? And in this case, if I'm looking for a range of 10 days, am I better off with a single range query or running 10 threads each one with a hashed key search for each date?
- Do I want to use a compound index and whether I can do something to optimize MongoDb search strategy (e.g. I want to minimize the number of documents scanned)?

Thanks!

Comment: Your mileage may vary based on your goals. Have you tried various date time structures yourself and see which one works best on high loads based on your application requirements?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't benchmarked anything. I guess I can test things empirically, but then I'll be able to answer my own question :). I was hoping to save time on benchmarking by asking the question here before I dive head-first into this.